# Working with 2 threads handling I/O respectively on same terminal window in C

Tags: c, multithreading, networking

I want to read input from a pthread using the terminal and output some text onto the same terminal using another pthread.

However, the output from one of the pthread is being read by the other one.

I read that ncurses may be used to divide the terminal and do both the stuff parallelly.

Is there any other way to do this on the same terminal window?

```
void* send_message(){
    char message[MESSAGE_BUFFER_LEN];
    while(1){
        memset(message,'\0',sizeof(message));strcat(message,username);
        printf("%s",username);
        fgets(message+strlen(message),MESSAGE_BUFFER_LEN-strlen(username),stdin);
        sendAll(message,strlen(message));
    }
}

void* recieve_message(){
    char message[MESSAGE_BUFFER_LEN];
    while(1){
        recv(socket_fd,message,MESSAGE_BUFFER_LEN,0);
        printf("%s",message);
        memset(message,'\0',MESSAGE_BUFFER_LEN);
    }   
}
```

The Input thread executes send_message and the output thread executes recieve_message.

However, whatever the output thread prints onto the terminal is picked up by the Input Thread(send_message).

I don't want that to happen.

The best way out of it that I've found till now is to create two windows using ncurses and run output on one and input on another.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [ask], and post an [mcve].  "Is there anyway to do X?", why yes of course there is.  Show us your work, ask a question related to a specific code related problem.  Don't ask open ended questions like that, they rarely yield useful results.

Comment: BTW: It sounds like one of your threads is reading or writing to the wrong stream.  Hard to tell though, because you didn't post any code.

Comment: Sorry for the insufficient question. I've added the thread codes and my progress till now.

Comment: What are the inputs?  What does the output look like?  Cut and past from your console window.  Both threads output data to the console without any coordination between them.  Is it possible you're interpreting the resulting mess incorrectly?  Try putting "P#:" prefix on each of the outputs, where '#' is any constant that uniquely identifies the source.  It might help you sort out exactly what is happening.

Comment: Your obviously not done writing your code.  It's also not an MCVE.  Given the input data and resulting outputs, it would be difficult for any of us to reproduce your issue(s), without making, possibly incorrect, assumptions about the rest of your code.  The process of creating a well packaged MCVE is often sufficient to prompt your own mind to resolve the issue yourself...

Comment: It's a discipline well worth learning, as it will save you many hours of spelunking.  By the time you reduce your code to a reproducible example, and attempt to explain what you are trying to achieve, you will find that you have your solution with fewer hours of effort on your part and ours.  When you have an MCVE, and still no solution, you can be confident it's not a trivial problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jumping ahead here while waiting on feedback from the OP.  I'll adjust if needed:

Your `printf()` and `fgets()` in `send_message` are not a single atomic operation.  Your `printf()` in `receive_message()` can post data to the console in-between the two `send_message()` operations.  This is a flawed design that can lead to confusing and often difficult to reproduce bugs.  Either redesign your program such that a single thread performs all console I/O tasks, or use a semaphore to control access to the shared console resources.

Since you are using pthreads, see: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html

Comment: Atomicity was the issue indeed, I'll include a MCVE asap. Thanks again.